# Update Firebase ref for KnockoutFire observable after bindings have been applied

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am currently using KnockoutJS with one viewmodel that has all the properties needed for my site. When I init the viewmodel at the very beginning, I make sure to assign null observables to the relevant properties so that when they are updated later on, events will be triggered. I am trying to do the same with a knockoutfire collection - specifically I want to load the data after the user has logged in without having to re-apply bindings - but it feels a bit heavy when I do it. This is what I've got, and the only way I actually was able to get it to work without re-applying bindings later on:

```
// init view model
var viewModel = {
    prop1: ko.observable(null),

    firebase1: KnockoutFire.observable(recommenderFirebase.child('ratings/suggestions'), {
        '.limit': 0,
        "$suggestion" : {
            accountID: true,
            itemID: true,
            relevance: true
        }
    });
}

// apply all bindings for life of app
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// login user and re-populate firebase1
firebaseOOO.initAuthClient(function(user) {
    viewModel.firebase1 = KnockoutFire.observable(recommenderFirebase.child('ratings/suggestions').child(user.id), {
        '.limit': 20,
        "$suggestion" : {
            accountID: true,
            itemID: true,
            relevance: true
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a better, cleaner, more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a wrapper observable then replacing the value of the observable after login?

First, applyBindings viewModel like this:

```
var viewModel = {
  prop1: ko.observable(null),
  afterLogin: ko.observable(null)
};
```

Then after logged in, set `afterLogin` new structure:

```
viewModel.afterLogin({
  firebase1: KnockoutFire.observable(…)
});
```

The corresponding view may look like this:

```
<!-- ko with: afterLogin -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: firebase1">
    <li><span data-bind="text: accountID"></span></li>
  </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[An idea sandbox of this answer at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiroshi/d4evK/).

Comment: That worked perfectly and is making the rendering much more efficient, thank you! In case anyone is trying it, it's a little unintuitive how works - pay attention that you are referencing "firebase1" in the html and not "afterLogin" as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Add amplify js to easily track loosely coupled pub/sub events. Define (subscribe) to the event before logging in, then publish the event when you login.